# How to offer extended RSS feed to premium users?

Tags: authentication, rss

I would like to provide extended RSS content (extended with unmoderated comments, for example) to premium users (moderators).

Would it be possible to somehow authenticate readers of feeds other than attaching a personal token string to the RSS URL?

Granted, this way a curious person only needs to steal an RSS link like this (much like one could steal a session id), but a password could be acquired just as easily, right?

How could I make this a bit more secure especially against [PEBKAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pebkac#Acronyms_and_other_names_for_a_user_error) issues?

Would you consider this an idea worth pursuing or should I just discard it and find some alternative? Could you suggest such an alternative?

Comment: I'd say discard, but maybe you are lucky and someone comes up with something. I doubt that, though, I really can't see how it could ever be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http authentication, like this [java example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html).
It, and your url idea, are in the open, so https is needed to prevent user/pass/session theft.

You would then also need user and session code, and password recovery code. You could try advertising before doing the work. Create a link, "Click here to pay X dollars for premium rss", and see if anyone uses it. I think there was a [stack overflow podcast](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html) that mentioned this, anyone remember which one?

Comment: I don't get it. RSS needs to be readable by external services (i.e. google reader): if those services do not support *whatever* system you use, it just won't work.

Comment: It's beneficial, but not necessarily a requirement for his feed to be readable by external services. His users could find and install a reader that supports his authentication, ie: feeddemon.